# What is the difference between offsite and onsite web analytic tools?

Tags: seo, google, google-analytics

What is the difference between onsite and offsite analytic tools?

I am reading a book about web analytic tools and this is the definition (from the book):

> **Offsite** web analytic's tools measure your potential website audience. They are the macro tools that allow you to see the bigger picture of how your website compares to others.
>
> **Onsite** web analytic's tools measure the actual visitor traffic arriving
>   on your website.

This doesn't make the distinction clear to me.  I generally understand about onsite tools, but offsite tools doesn't make sense.

Comment: Offsite = data gathered from sites other than your own, eg your position in Google comes from Google, not you and so would require offsite analytics to collect that.

Comment: @Richard B, Can you please explain me, how offsite tools complement onsite tools?

Comment: It's useful to know things like where you are in Google.  It's also useful to know how many hits you have.  Off-site and On-site is just about how this data is collected.  Data is only as useful as you make it, and so it compliments if you can use both in your analysis.

Comment: For example, you may want to compare position in Google and hits to your site in order to see if there is a pattern.  That would require both off-site and on-site data.

Comment: Don't get data for the sake of getting data.  Collect data because you can see a use in it.

Comment: Offsite tools will basically help you to check your position in google search. I got it now..Thanks a lot..!! :)

Comment: with the help of offsite tools, you can compare your website position with the other websites

Comment: Not *just* Google, that's an example - any data you can't gather from your site alone would require an offsite tool to get it.

Comment: Offsite is data which is gathered NOT on your site. For e.g GA (Google Analytics) provides you with industry benchmarking (how your site performs v/s the industry average).

Comment: All fine answers now that the question is open. @CRazyProgrammer you can add your own answer too if you've developed a better understanding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Offsite analytics** would include any tools that analyze traffic on your website through tools not served with the web page or directly connected to the web server in any way.

A good example would be Google analytics which can give you a good idea of the amount of traffic on your site, but because it does not have direct access to your website can only show traffic coming from Google. Another example would be Alexa which gathers data derived from various browser plugins to see how much traffic a site receives.

**Onsite analytics** would include tools like Google Analytics which is served as a cookie with the webpage, and cPanel's built in analytics would also be included since it directly monitors the traffic to and from your web server.